# Prawn PDF Encryption Bit Increase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I used Prawn to generate PDF's in Rails and I noted that in the [documentation](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/security.rb) from line 76 that:

> The encryption used is weak; the key is password-derived and islimited to 40 bits, due to US export controls in effect at the time the PDF standard was written. There is nothing technologically requiring PDF readers to respect the permissions embedded in a document. Many PDF readers do not. In short, you have **no security at all** against a moderately motivated person. Don't use this for anything super-serious. This is not a limitation of Prawn, but is rather a built-in limitation of the PDF format.

I understand you can easily get around the encryption, but the law in my country requires 128 bit encryption. Is there a way to increase it in Prawn PDF?

Comment: Prawns use of PDF standard 1.3 is very old. For instance PDF 1.4 released in 2001 started allowing for RC4 implementations of 40 to 128 bits, PDF 1.7 (2006) offered RC4 and AES up to 128 bits and PDF 2.0 (2020) now allows for AES 256. Maybe open something with Prawn to see if they will/can update their security measures. In the meantime if possible take a look at whether or not HexaPDF can suit your needs AES128 appears to be their default encryption.

Comment: @engineersmnky are you sure they use PDF 1.3? The manual refers to PDF 1.6?

Comment: At the top of the file you posted it states: *"Implements PDF encryption (password protection and permissions) as specified in the PDF Reference, version 1.3, section 3.5 "Encryption"."*

Comment: @KJ I understand encryption provides no security for a PDF, the top dogs (they call themselves that) at my national tax authority doesnt realise this, but requires it. The irony, when they request the submission of supporting documents, it may not be encrypted, but dont let them catch you sending an unencrypted financial document to anyone else. I didnt realise the encryption of Prawn was so low when I started, but lets see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you could use [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) instead of Prawn for generating your documents and use AES 128bit or 256bit encryption. This, however, would mean you need to completely revamp your code as the document creation facilities are a bit different.

What would be easier for you is to post-process your Prawn generated PDF document to encrypt it in a second step. I.e. first create the document using Prawn *without* encryption and then apply the encryption afterwards.

The second step could be done using HexaPDF directly after generating the PDF document with Prawn, inside the same Ruby process. Or you can use any of the CLI tools that allow this, like `hexapdf` (the CLI companion of the HexaPDF library), `qpdf`, `pdftk`...

[N.b. I'm the author of HexaPDF.]

Comment: thank you, the second option to post create encrypt seems good